# I can't instantiate a simple class in Python

Tags: python

I want to generate a Python class via a file.
This is a very simple file, named testy.py:

```
def __init__(self,var):
    print (var)
```

When I try to instantiate it I get:

```
>>> import testy
>>> testy('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Then , I try something else:

```
class testy_rev1:
    def __init__(self,var):
    print (var)
```

I try to instanicate it and I get:

```
>>> import testy_rev1
>>> a=testy_rev1('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> a=testy_rev1.testy_rev1('1')
1
```

What I am looking for is a way to import it from a file w/o resorting to:

```
import <module name>.<module name>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attempt 1 failed because you were not defining a class, just a function (which you fixed with attempt 2).

Attempt 2 is failing because you looking at the `import` statement like it is a Java `import` statement. In Python, an `import` makes a module object that can be used to access items inside it. If you want use a class with in a module without first specifying the module you want to use the following:

```
from my_module import MyClass
a = MyClass()
```

As a side note, your print method in the 2nd attempt in not indented after the `__init__` method. This might just me a formatting error when you posted here, but it will not run the code how you expect.

Answer (score 2):

With a file called testy.py with this:

```
class testy_rev1:
    def __init__(self, var):
        print (var)
```

You will have to do either:

```
>>> import testy
>>> testy.testy_rev1('1')
```

Or:

```
>>> from testy import testy_rev1
>>> testy_rev1('1')
```

Or (not recommended, since you will not see where the definition came from in the source):

```
>>> from testy import *
>>> testy_rev1('1')
```

Other than that I do not know how you could do it.

Comment: @Lior please mark the question as answered if it actually did answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

`import x` imports a module called `x`. `import y.x` imports the module `d` from the module/package `y`. Anything in this module is refered to as `x.stuff` or `y.x.stuff`. That's how it works and they won't change the language for your convenience ;)

You can always do `from module import thingy`. But consider that importing the whole module is usually preferred over this... for a reason (to make clearer where it came from, to avoid namespace clashes, because "explicit is better than mplicit")!